# XML sound's byte form

Tags: c#, xml, audio, soundplayer

I have a .wav file and i write this byte form to XML. I want to play this song on my form but I am not sure I am correct and it doesn't work.  Str is my file's byte form.

```
byte[] soundBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(soundBytes, 0, soundBytes.Length);
ms.Write(soundBytes, 0, soundBytes.Length);
SoundPlayer ses = new SoundPlayer(ms);
ses.Play();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are initializing your `MemoryStream` with a buffer, and then writing that same buffer to the stream.  So, the stream starts off with a given buffer of data, and then you're overwriting it with an identical buffer, but in the process you're also changing the current position within the stream to the very end.

```
byte[] soundBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(soundBytes, 0, soundBytes.Length);
// ms.Position is 0, the beginning of the stream
ms.Write(soundBytes, 0, soundBytes.Length);
// ms.Position is soundBytes.Length, the end of the stream
SoundPlayer ses = new SoundPlayer(ms);
// ses tries to play from a stream with no more bytes to consume
ses.Play();
```

Remove the call to `ms.Write()` and see if it works.